# Is there a user-friendly interface I can type MongoDB queries at?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, but have gone pretty far with studying some of the fundamentals. So far, I have been using the mongo shell to write my queries. I was wondering if anyone here can introduce me to a simple and straightforward user-friendly interface I can use to type out my queries.
I have examined Studio3T and Robo3T. Both do not really meet my requirements as they are too heavy and full of menus I don't need at the moment. I am tempted to go on a wild search and download spree, but I figured some help here might be a better approach.

I need it to be the following:

-Simple and lightweight

-Completes curly and square brackets

-May or may not offer error checks while writing queries

-May or may not offer auto-complete of keywords.

I'd really appreciate any pointers. Thanks

Comment: use MongoDB compass

Comment: Thanks! I have compass, but only just figured out how to write scripts in it after you mentioned this.

Comment: Go to the official documentation of MongoDB http://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/query/filter/